# unresolved external symbol "public: static struct Node::Children Node::children" (?children@Node@@2UChildren@1@A)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct

I have a .h (lets call it A.h) file with the following struct

```
static struct Children {
        std::string leftChild = "left";
        std::string rightChild = "right";
    } children;
```

and this has been used multiple times within this file.

A.h is #included in another .h file(lets call it B.h);

in my cpp file which is currently:

```
#include"B.h"

int main(){return 0;}
```

and running the cpp file gives the

> unresolved external symbol "public: static struct Node::Children Node::children" (?children@Node@@2UChildren@1@A)

error

however directly including A.h works fine.

What should i do?

P.S. this question may be dumb but im just starting out so i have no idea how to even phrase this question properly

Comment: You've left something out, I'm afraid.  I've made an A.h, included it in B.h and included B.h in main.cpp and cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to add the following line in one of the .cpp `Children children;` to instantiate the class instance.

Comment: @ALX23z No, it's instantiated in the declaration.

Comment: @JasperKent It's not obvious from the code, but the error message makes it clear that `children` is declared as a static member of class `Node`; it's not a standalone variable. Such a declaration does require a separate definition. It should be `Node::Children Node::children;` in one source file.

Comment: @JasperKent static variables cannot be initialized in declaration.  There will be inline version in the future but current one cannot. C++ requires to know which translation unit initializes the variable. IgorTandetnik wrote the correct instantiation declaration.

Comment: @ALX23z If the Children struct is embedded in a class, yes. But that's not what the code shows.

Comment: @JasperKent yes the struct is inside the class. Im sorry i didnt include that pat i thought it wouldnt be significnt. Im sorry

Comment: @YunusPoonawala Can you put the full code up?